# Getting Iframe src from a XML using Xpath

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I am trying to get an iframe src from a XML for showing it in a **WebView**. For this i am using XPath for getting the value. Currently i am trying to parse [this iframe](http://pastebin.com/DgdiWrFV). But i am not getting any value at all.

I have tried this **XPath**:

```
"//GoodreadsResponse/book/reviews_widget/iframe[@id=\"the_iframe\"]/@src/text()"
```

Is my XPath wrong for getting this iframe src? Full xml is [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=2LbbmGUeNFCEVdeZaux6hw&title=vinci+code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another answer will correct me, but I don't think XPath will parse data within the `CDATA` section.

You can do this in two steps, however.

1. Grab the text section of `//GoodreadsResponse/book/reviews_widget`
2. This is the `CDATA` section before.  It's not XML as it is (multiple root elements), but we can add a parent element and then parse it.

I will include a .NET snippet which hopefully you can convert.

```
    XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("//GoodreadsResponse/book/reviews_widget");
    String cdataText = node.InnerText;

    // The cdataText here isn't quite XML, as it has multiple roots.
    // let's surround it by a single root element
    String xml = "<root>" + cdataText + "</root>";

    XmlDocument innerDoc = new XmlDocument();
    innerDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNode srcAttr = innerDoc.SelectSingleNode("/root/div/iframe[@id=\"the_iframe\"]/@src");

    // This prints out https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&format=html&isbn=0307277674&links=660&min_rating=&review_back=fff&stars=000&text=000
    Console.WriteLine(srcAttr.Value);
```

Comment: I have successfully able to do it in java using your technique. Thanks for the idea. @jglouie